# How to Pass App Settings to Mail Method in C#

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-code, configuration, smtp

I'm trying to pass the App Settings keys listed into the Send Email function so they can be customized by the user, but for some reason I can't get it to work. I've been testing with the "Body" key to see if I can even get 1 to work.

**App Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="MailHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <add key="PortNumber" value="587" />
        <add key="MailPassword" value="**********" />
        <add key="Recipient" value="*************appspotmail.com" />
        <add key="Body" value="Sent from WOX Mail Plugin." />
        <add key="MailUser" value="**********@gmail.com" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Main.CS File**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Wox.Plugin;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace Wox.Plugin.Version1
{
    public class Main :IPlugin
    {
        public void Init(PluginInitContext context)
        {
        }
        public List<Result> Query(Wox.Plugin.Query query)
        {
            var subject = query.Search;
            string emailbody = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Body");
            return new List<Result>()
            {
                new Result()
                {
                  Title = string.Format("Add: {0}",  subject),
                  IcoPath = "Images\\icon.png",
                  SubTitle = "Send New Task to Marvin",
                  Action = (Func<ActionContext, bool>) (c =>
                  {
                    Main.SendEmail(subject, emailbody);
                    return true;
                  })
                }
            };
        }
        public static void SendEmail(string inputsubject, string body)
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress("****************");
                message.To.Add("********************8");
                message.Subject = inputsubject;
                message.Body = body;
                message.IsBodyHtml = false;
                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    smtpClient.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)new NetworkCredential("*************", "************");
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It feels like I've tried placing the ConfigurationManager line in every perceivable spot to make it happen, and nothing has worked. The subject goes through fine, but not the body.

The email always sends successfully, but the information in the body doesn't send. I've also tried appending it to the subject line, but it doesn't show up there either.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through it to see what body contains when its assigned to message. Also you should probably assign IsBodyHtml before assigning the body in case the get method resets the body.

Comment: Try to use key lookup. I.e. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body"] instead.`

Comment: Body is the only value to come from the configuration file so it is not sending the email that is the issue. It is reading values from the configuration that is causing the issue.

Comment: @LinkedListT I tried that, still not showing up.